# Releasing and Renewing your DHCP-based IP Address

Tags: c#, network-programming

Using C# how can I release and renew my DHCP-based IP Address?

At the moment I am using the process method to use these DOS commands:

```
ipconfig /release
```

and

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Is there a more managed approach in C# for this?

Comment: I think the usual approach to this sort of thing is exactly how you are doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **could** use WMI, but its much simpler to just do it using `System.Diagnostics.Process`

Here is a WMI solution anyway:

```
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    //Need to determine which adapter here with some kind of if() statement
    objMO.InvokeMethod("ReleaseDHCPLease", null, null);
    objMO.InvokeMethod("RenewDHCPLease", null, null); 
}
```

Comment: hi, I shall give that a go now. Thanks

Comment: Could I do it without `foreach`? Is there any way to directly call  `objMO.InvokeMethod("ReleaseDHCPLease", null, null)`?  Like: `var objMO = new ManagementObject(@"root/cimv2, $"Win32_NetWorkAdapterConfiguration", null);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_NetworkAdapter", "AdapterTypeID=0");
  ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
  foreach (ManagementObject result in search.Get())
  {
    NetworkAdapter adapter = new NetworkAdapter(result);
    adapter.Disable();
  }
```

Not that your process must have elevated privileges.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, I shall give that a go now. Thanks